# Rails fragment caching after database reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using fragment caching in Rails and it works really well. But after `db:reset`, which occurs common at this stage of the project, the last used fragment cache still applies.

How can I expire it together with db:reset? Is the only solution creating new rake task with other name that bundles `db:reset` with `expire_fragment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rake tmp:cache:clear` would clean fragment caching

Enhance db:reset task

```
Rake::Task["db:reset"].enhance do
  Rake::Task["tmp:cache:clear"].invoke
end
```

Comment: How should I name this file? Can I just place this in 'tasks'?

Comment: Yeah, I've named it db.rake, and placed in tasks and it works. Thanks!